# Add MIME type for .htc files on Heroku with Flask

Tags: python, heroku, flask, pie-chart

I am trying to include the PIE.htc (http://www.css3pie.com/) file in my css to fix some problems in IE.  I inlcude the line

```
behavior: url(/static/pie/PIE.htc);
```

for the relevant classes.  This doesn't appear to load.

From reading around, it seems that I need to add the MIME type

```
text/x-component
```

for .htc files on my Heroku application that is using Flask.

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I thought that maybe something similar to the following would work, but it seems not to.

```
@app.route('/PIE.htc')
def pie():
    handle = open('static/pie/PIE.htc','r+')
    return Response(handle, mimetype = 'text/x-component')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me. Here is my complete test application:

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    handle = open(__file__, 'r+') 
    return flask.Response(handle, mimetype='test/x-component')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This serves itself with the desired `Content-Type: test/x-component` header in the HTTP response.

Run my test app:

```
(test)day@office:~/test$ python test.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
```

In another terminal, use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) to make a HEAD request for just the headers:

```
day@office:~$ curl -Is http://127.0.0.1:5000/
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: test/x-component
Connection: close
Server: Werkzeug/0.8.3 Python/2.7.3
Date: Fri, 30 Nov 2012 00:29:39 GMT
```

If this also works for you when run locally, then it might have something to do with the Heroku runtime environment? I'm not familiar with Heroku but perhaps they run your app behind a reverse proxy which eats Content-Types it is not configured to handle?